# Costo de envío de varios productos de un carrito con Mercado Envíos

Tags: php, mercadopago

No sé cuál es la manera correcta y mejor para calcular el costo de envío de un carrito de compras con mas de un producto. Usando:

```
$mp->get("/shipping_options", $params);
```

Cuando la dimension es mayor a 70x70x70, me da `Invalid dimensions`. Según [esta página](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/use-mercadoenvios/) la dimensiones deberían ser expresadas en centímetros.

Las consultas que tengo son:

- ¿Cuáles son los valores límites de alto, ancho y largo?
- Si tengo mas de un producto en un carrito(distinto o igual), la manera correcta es llamar a la función una vez por producto del carrito y sumar el costo de envío total? O hay una manera de mandarle distintos productos con distintas dimensiones y que mercado envíos calcule el costo de envío de la manera mas óptima ??? (quizás entre más de un producto en una caja)

Comment: Hola.. deberias mirar https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/por-qu%C3%A9-no-somos-soporte-al-cliente-de-tu-compa%C3%B1%C3%ADa-favorita ...